# Regex javascript search word but ignore couple of words

Tags: javascript, regex

Good afternoon,

Would like to know if it is possible to search a word but ignore the same word with other word in regex.

Example : 
        One : Two : Three : Four : Five : Six : Two Three : Nine

Answer : 
        One : Two : **Three** : Four : Five : Six : Two Three : Nine

So the regex only found the first word Three and ignore Two Three.

I tried this regex :

```html
(?!Two Three)(Three)
```

but it doesn't work, it does work if the word is two

Any help or suggestions i'd gladly appreciate. Thanks

Comment: So you just want to take the word when it's between double dots ?

Comment: Not really because it can start or finish with Three (ex : Three : One : Two : [...] : Three)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input `One : Two : Three : Four : Five : Six : Two Three : Nine`

in which you want to ignore `Two Three` you can do

```
let str = 'One : Two : Three : Four : Five : Six : Two Three : Nine';
let re = /Two(?!\sThree)/g;
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for something more generic I suggest a pure js approach:

```js
let str = 'One : Two : Three : Four : Five : Six : Two Three : Nine';

let resp = str
  .split(' : ')
  .reduce((acc, ele) => acc.some(x => ele.search(x) > 0) ? acc : acc.concat(ele), [])
  .join(' : ');
  
console.log(resp);
```